# ¿Problemas a la hora de combinar varias aplicaciones desarrolladas en Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, programación-móvil

El problema que tengo es que, tengo varias aplicaciones instaladas en el teléfono programadas en Xamarin, pero estoy desarrollando una que cuando la instalo para iniciar la depuración me bloquea el inicio de las demás, es decir, que no me inician ninguna aplicación que este programada con Xamarin, instalada en el mismo teléfono.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: No lo he probado, pero ¿es posible que hayas depurado las otras aplicaciones con el mismo movil?

Comment: si la instalacion de las otras aplicaciones las has hecho desde debug, prueba a instalarlas desde apk y comenta por aqui el resultado que me interesa por curiosidad!

Comment: Revisa en el dispositivo > aplicaciones instaladas en la tarjeta de memoria si hay una aplicacion llamada Mono Shared Runtime instalada y eliminala. No puedes tener apk de versiones de Xamarin diferentes en depuración. Luego vuelve a reinstalar los Apk nuevamente.